# How do I enable showing hotkeys in the game?

Tags: starcraft-2

On some Starcraft II stream I have seen bigger mouse pointers or some kind of overlay where the hotkeys are shown over each button, e.g. in the build menu. How can I enable that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Gameplay options menu you can select a checkbox for "Command Hotkey Text".

Comment: I could imagine this impacting PC performance, at least on lower specced machines. Does it?

Comment: I can't imagine how. I believe all it does is put the key up in the corner of the box. Very simple operation as far as graphics are concerned.

Comment: It does not seem to impact PC performance for me, but it definitely improves my performance. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In case your searhing and you want to get back to the command card displaying shortcut keys:
In gameplay options uncheck 'Enable simple command card'.